# I have two panel side by side in content page.when click on button on 1st panel 2nd panel fields are responding

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

**this is my html code**

```
 <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg dashbard-1">
     <div class="content-top">
      <%-- <div class="row"--%>
    <iframe src="http://www.gmail.com" style="width: 1350px; height:650px">
 </iframe>
  </div>  
</div>
```

when i load this page it is redirecting to gmail ste.
can tell me what is problem

Answer (score 0):

Your whole page is filled with iframe and that iframe s loading gmail.com.

Comment: then 
how can i load gmail into my web page

Comment: If you want to show gmail in your website, your code is exactly doing what you asked for. Please rephrase your question so that we can understand the exact issue you are looking for.